# Making black edges on the top and bottom of view controllers for iPhone 5 apps permanent

Tags: iphone, xcode, storyboard

I don't want to remove iPhone 5 support, I just want it so that it would be exactly like apps that have not been updated for iPhone 5's screen (where the black strips line the top and bottom on all view controllers).

Edit: Below is a picture showing what I mean. Also, my storyboard error log (yellow exclamation point in the side column) is showing that there, indeed, is NO iPhone 5 picture. Yet, it still loads up as though there is one.

Edit 2: I have created another new project and tried going in and deleting the actual file first (not from the one when you click on the target) and that worked. Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the letterboxes that are created when the app does not scale, remove the Default-568h@2x.png image from your project. By default, there is a black filler image in Project Summary under Launch Images. Remove that one, and it should still letterbox.

Comment: No, it still tries to expand the view controllers even though I have deleted it.

Comment: It's probably still in the cached build. Remove the app from your phone and do a clean build. The question remains: *why* do you want to do this?

Comment: Just did that. Didn't work. But thanks though. I want to do this because that would force me to have to redesign my entire app, all 94 view controllers. I don't want to do that, but Apple really should have a way to turn off this fragmentation situation

Comment: Did you make sure to actually delete the image from the Finder folder? I have heard that it can still make a difference if it gets included with the build package, even though it is not shown as a Launch Image.

Comment: Yes. Strangely enough, they actually come back after 12 hours. And even when they are not there, they still cause the screen to be iPhone 5 size.

Comment: Do you set a frame size in your view controllers? if you set it to the bounds of the screen, instead of specifying the hight and width, it could be using that setting. I am out of ideas as to why removing that launch image is not working.

Comment: Yes, but that only affects the storyboard design display....Can you give it a go on a new project on your end? Let me know if it works, cause when I did that, it didn't.